# WPF where can i find the default style of treeview's togglebuton?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, treeview, togglebutton

I was following a tutorial on how to modify the controltemplate, but the tutorial overrides the original toggle button with a new togglebutton that uses a Path to draw a triangle, rather than the original crosshair shaped expander. Does the original exist somewhere that I can just reference in a style? or am I going to have to just draw it using a rectangle and paths?

```
<Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
          <Grid
          Width="15"
          Height="13"
          Background="Transparent">
            <Path x:Name="ExpandPath"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Margin="1,1,1,1"
            Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
            Data="M 4 0 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z"/>
          </Grid>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
               Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Data"
                TargetName="ExpandPath"
                Value="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z"/>
            </Trigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

and elsewhere

```
           <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                  Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"
                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                  ClickMode="Press"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find [default styles on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx).

If you want to reference a style you need to add reference to `PresentationFramework.Aero` (or any other theme) and merge the resources. However, it breakes theme "magic", so copying the style to your resources is probably a better idea.

Comment: so you gave me the style, but if I copy all the xaml over into the usercontrol resources, it seems rather huge. Is that standard? or is there a way to link other xaml files. I feel like it would make sense to have another file "treeviewitem.xaml" that contained the styles for just treeviewitem. I am making a custom control, so it seems rather huge to have a custom style taking up so much of the xaml for the control. The only thing I actually wanted done was to make the children line up with the parent by giving a margin of -19 to the itemspresenter in the control temlpate.

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet It's a common problem with WPF: either the designer of the control makes something configurable in the template, or you have to copy a lot of code. It's a step forward from WinForms though, where templating is not available at all. If you want to avoid copy-pasting at all costs, see ["wpf force theme"](https://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+force+theme) (there are multiple solutions, but none of them are perfect).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Expander control like this.

```
<Grid>
    <Expander Name="PART_Expander" IsExpanded="{TemplateBinding TreeViewItem.IsExpanded}">
         <Expander.Header>
            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" />
         </Expander.Header>
            <ItemsPresenter />
    </Expander>
    <ContentPresenter Name="PART_ContentPresenter" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Grid>
```